# Rule for combination of email adresses

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules, microsoft

Currently trying to set-up some rules to manage email more efficiently. In this case I'd like to move emails automatically whenever they are sent to a specific set of collegues I'm in a seperate project with.

The project contains of 6 collegues. Whenever one of them sents an email to me and all other remaining collegues, it should be moved to a folder with the project name. Of only one is missing, I'd like the emails not to be moved (due to different priorities).

How can I best create the rules to achieve the desired outcome? Thanks!

Comment: It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a rule as shown in the below figure, and then click the from field to type all the addresses you want:
[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.